# What is the definiteness of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, positive-definite, hessian-matrix

I am trying to calculate the extrema of the function $$f(x,y) = \sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(x+y)$$ with the constraint $0 < x, y,x+y < \pi$. I have determined the critical point to be $\left( \frac{\pi}{3} , \frac{\pi}{3} \right)$. Now I want to determine whether this is a maximum or a minimum. For that, I would obviously need the Hessian matrix and its determinant or eigenvalues. I get

$$H(f)\left( \frac{\pi}{3} , \frac{\pi}{3} \right) = \begin{pmatrix}
-\sqrt{3} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\sqrt{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Its determinant is easily calculated to be $\det(H) = 2.25$. However, its eigenvalues are both negative and judging from a plot the point should actually refer to a maximum. Something's got to be wrong here, since the determinant should be negative.

Comment: If you have two distinct negative eigenvalues, their determinant which is the product of the eigenvalues should be positive. May this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: The confusion is that the point should be a maximum, which doesn't add up with a positive determinant.

Comment: If your two eigenvalues are positive/negative then your point is a local minimum/maximum. In particular, the sign of the determinant doesn't tell you whether it is a maximum or minimum. (If your eigenvalues differ by signs, it's a saddle point). There's no contradiction as far as I can see.

Comment: Well, it says in our script that the Hesse matrix having a positive / negative determinant refers to the function having a minimum / maximum in that point.

Comment: Write the quadratic form $x^T H x$. Its sign will tell you how the function behaves locally.

Comment: @TeamPhysics What you said should only be true for 1d. In general, the determinant of the Hessian is just not enough to determine the local behavior.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Sinc eigenvalues are usually impossible to compute (although not for $2\times2$), you might be interested in Sylvester's criterion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Answer (score 1):

I'll restrict the discussion to symmetric marices, since we are talking about the Hessian matrix, which is symmetric.An equivalent condition for negative definiteness, but much easier to compute (especially if the matrix is large)is that the principal minors of odd order must be negative and the principal minors of even order must be positive. Even easier, and also equivalent, is that, for an nxn matrix, the determinant of the upper left rxr corner must be negative if r is odd and positive if r is even for $1\le r \le n$. Buy  and study Ferrar's old book "Algebra-Atext-book of determinants, matrices and algebraic forms" (Oxford U.P. 1957)